# Omnigroup frameworks dependency

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos

The OmniUnzip framework is linked to 2 other frameworks : OmniBase and OmniFoundation.

Because I just need the OmniUnzip framework in my app. Is it enough to just link it to my target and copy it into my app bundle ?

Or do I need to also copy the OmniBase and OmniFoundation frameworks in my app bundle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's dependent on the other frameworks, you need to include them too.

Easy enough to test - if you get linker errors without them, but don't with them, then you need them.  :)

Just because you aren't calling methods in those other frameworks doesn't mean the OmniUnzip framework isn't.

Comment: Yeah I made some tests to better understand. I need to include them. Thanks.